# Validar campo com ajax e php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com um simples form, para validar se um nome e email existem.

```js
function valida_nome(){
 var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
 if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
 document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
  document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
  }
  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="valida_ajax_js.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
  <h1>Agenda de Contatos utilizando AJAX</h1>
  <hr/>
  <h2>Pesquisar Contato:</h2>
  <form id="form_user_cad" name="form_user_cad" method="POST"  action="">
 <input type="text" id="input_nome_cad" name="nome_cad" placeholder="Nome e Sobrenome"    autofocus   onblur="valida_nome()"><br/>
 <input type="text" id="input_email_cad" name="email_cad" placeholder="Insira o Email" ><br/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn_enviar_cad"  name="enviar_cad"  value="Criar Conta">
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

***Se tentar digitar algum dos caracteres especiais verá que não é possível.***

Até aqui está exatamente como eu quero, pois o usuário não pode avançar para outro campo enquanto não preencher corretamente o campo.

A seguir, o código do Ajax para verificar se o nome que foi digitado corretamente já existe, caso não exista, pode prosseguir ao próximo campo, mas se existir quero que tenha o mesmo comportamento da verificação dos caracteres, ou seja o usuário não consiga avançar.

Código Ajax

```js
function CriaRequest() {
 try{
 request = new XMLHttpRequest();        
 }catch (IEAtual){
  try{
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");       
        }catch(IEAntigo){
         try{
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");          
            }catch(falha){
             request = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert("Seu Navegador não suporta Ajax!");
    else
    return request;
}
function nome_existe() {
 var nome = document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value;
 var xmlreq = CriaRequest();
 xmlreq.open("GET", "mysqli_select_ajax.php?nome_cad=" + nome, true);
 xmlreq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlreq.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlreq.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value="";
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = xmlreq.responseText;
      document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
   document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
   return true;
   }
  }
 };
 xmlreq.send(null);
}
```

E o código do banco com php

```html
<?php
// Verifica se existe a variável txtnome
if (isset($_GET["nome_cad"])) {
    $nome = $_GET["nome_cad"];
    // Conexao com o banco de dados
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $base = "bd_";
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $senha, $base);
 
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 
 if (!empty($nome)) {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome_cad like '$nome' ";
    }else{
 echo "Insira um nome";
 return;
 }   
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($linha['nome_cad'] != $nome ){        
     echo $nome;
    }else {
        // Se a consulta não retornar nenhum valor, exibi mensagem para o usuário
        echo "Nome já existe!";
    }
} 
?>
```

### A dúvida

Como eu junto a função valida_nome() com a função do AJax, para que a função nome_existe() seja inicializada após a 1º checagem ter sido realiza e à partir do "onblur" do input name="nome_cad"?

O arquivo do banco está ok, e o ajax tmb, pois se eu separar eles desta função valida_nome, eles funcionam direitinho, faz a checagem e se tiver o nome no banco ele avisa, se não ele retorna o nome digitado.

O problema mesmo é juntar para eles funcionarem na sequência mencionada acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrescente um `return false`, caso não seja válido, e `return true` caso seja válido:

```
function valida_nome(){
    var filter_nome = /^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]|\s)+$/ ;
    if(!filter_nome.test(document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value)){
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").value='';
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").placeholder = "Nome inválido";
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = "#ff0000";
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").focus();
        document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").onkeydown = function keydown_nome(){
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.borderColor = "#999999";
            document.getElementById("input_nome_cad").style.outline = null;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Depois na `nome_existe()` pode colocar isto logo na abertura:

```
function nome_existe() {
    if(!valida_nome()) { // caso seja inválido
       alert('Nome Invalido');
       return;
    }
    ...
}
```

E, se percebi bem no `onblur` do input fica:

```
onblur="nome_existe()"
```

Comment: Opsss, periii, tho ver..

Comment: Acho que deu belooo, thô só configurar direitinho aqui....

Comment: Nota 10 perfect....Vlw ;)

Comment: De nada @MagicHat ..